# Add HyperLink Column to Datatable

Tags: rest, datatable

I am trying to add a hyperlink to the Fac_x0020_ID column in the datatable below. How is this done with datatables?

```
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$('#FacilitiesTable').dataTable({
"bDestroy": true,
"bProcessing": true,
"bPaginate" : false,
"bInfo" : false,
"bFilter" : false,
"aaData": data.d.results,
"aoColumns": [
{ "mData": "Title" },
{ "mData": "Fac_x0020_ID" },
{ "mData": "INSNO"},
{ "mData": "Building_x0020_Status" },
{ "mData": "State" },
{ "mData" : "Show_x0020_on_x0020_Links_x0020_" }
]
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the promised update wherein I combine multiple columns of the data to form a more user friendly hyperlink:

```
$('#FacilitiesTable').dataTable({
"bDestroy": true,
"bProcessing": true,
"bPaginate" : false,
"bInfo" : false,
"bFilter" : false,
"aaData": data.d.results,
"aoColumns": [
{ "mData": null , 
     "mRender" : function ( data, type, full ){ 
        return "<a href='https://www.WesternConstruction.com/Facility2013.aspx?FacID=" + full['Fac_x0020_ID'] + "' >"+full['INSNO'] + " - (" +full['Fac_x0020_ID'] + ") -- " +full['Title']+"</a>"
        }
},
{ "mData" : 'Building_x0020_Status' }
]
});
});
call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
alert("Error retrieving Facilities: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched with [**`https://www.google.nl/search?q=datatables+render+link`**](https://www.google.nl/search?q=datatables+render+link) ??

There is elaborate documentation in: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: Yeah, I did a *lot* of searching. The issue is there seem to be multiple versions/ways to do this with a datatable, with no explanation about what the various parameters mean. --- I got my answer last night (see below) but I've now got to figure out how to combine elements of the data to make the link more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer, here is what I did:

```
$('#FacilitiesTable').dataTable({
"bDestroy": true,
"bProcessing": true,
"bPaginate" : false,
"bInfo" : false,
"bFilter" : false,
"aaData": data.d.results,
"aoColumns": [
{ "mData": "Title" },
{
    "mData": "Fac_x0020_ID", 
    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
        return "<a href='https://www.WesternConstruction.com/Facility2013.aspx?FacID=" + data + "'>" + data + "</a>";
    }
},
{ "mData": "INSNO"},
{ "mData": "Building_x0020_Status" },
{ "mData": "State" },
{ "mData" : "Show_x0020_on_x0020_Links_x0020_" }
]
});
```

Not sure how you would combine other elements of the data to make the display text of the link more meaningful. If I figure that out, I will post an update.